# How should literary/fictional words, derived from the anglicization of other languages, be pronounced?

Tags: proper-nouns, anglicization

We often see peculiar names being given to titles and fictional characters, such as Wolfenstein (which protagonist does also have a weird name: Blazkowicz).

I would spend long times trying to figure out how I should pronounce these, but when I see a video of someone pronouncing it "correctly" (in the original language), I find out I were saying it very differently! However, these names are anglicized, as in used in English language fiction, such that the pronounce might not be the original one either.

Is there any consensus as to whether we should pronounce these names as if they were from their original language, or any standard to pronounce their anglicized forms?

Comment: It's worth noting that Wolfenstein is a game released in English and Blazkowicz is "an American spy of Polish and Jewish descent" (Wikipedia). As such, it's a little confusing to talk about "the original language". Is the name pronounced at any point in the games themselves?

Comment: Slavic and/or Polish names are one thing; and the issue exists in any language. Wolfenstein is, however, not anything other than invention, and easy to pronounce.

Comment: @Lambie it's easy to pronounce in at least two ways: as if it started with the English word *wolf* and carried on as English, and something approximating *Volfenshtein* (pseudo-German; IPA on my phone isn't going to happen).

Comment: @ChrisH Easier is Wolf+ en+ stein, isn't it?  See, Mommy, no IPA [snigger, snigger]. [joke]

Comment: Surely it depends whether the fictional character is from another country, or an English-speaking person whose forebears happened to come from overseas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Law of Hobson-Jobson](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobson-Jobson#Law_of_Hobson-Jobson) maintains that words borrowed from another language will be conformed to the sound set of the borrowing language. I would add two corollaries:

- Even if the original has no sounds foreign to English, if the original spelling suggests an English pronunciation, then English will likely win the day
- unless elite speakers approximating the original pronunciation manage to convince others to pronounce it their way.

Most Americans pronounce the German car Volkswagen as *VOKES-wagon*, although the German *FOLKS-vahgen* contains no sounds not present in English. The spelling wins out. The television show *Grimm* overflows with mangled German that's been thoroughly "englished."

Elite speakers will pronounce the names of composers as closely to the original as they can, so the composer Wagner (*VAHG-ner*) is pronounced differently then someone named Wagner they happen to know. There are, however, limits. The ř in Dvořák is a rare and difficult sound, so most approximate it with a zh-sound. French nasalized vowels also are readily jettisoned.

This means that the gaming community can basically pronounce names as they see fit. Wolfenstein looks German, so you can pronounce it as *VOLF'n-shtine* if you like, or like a VW, go for pronouncing it as if it were an English name. Polish orthography is rather daunting, but as a last resort, ask someone from Chicago. The Windy City has a high concentration of Polish-Americans. Plus you can get into an argument about pizza.

Comment: In British English, *Volkswagen* usually has an audible *L* and a short *O* but we pronounce the *V* and *W* as in English. We don't have many Wagners, and tend to pronounce the composer reasonably correctly, as with Bach. In that case though, there are people with that surname who pronounce it to rhyme with aitch.

Comment: @ChrisH Speak for yourself! *Volkswagen* is pronounced with a v in the middle. And *Porsche* does (but not often) have the terminal *-e* pronounced as well.

Comment: I'm personally slightly inconsistent with *Volkswagen*, preferring the *v* sound for the *w* but preferring to avoid funny looks. And the *e* of *Porsche* seems more common than not.

Comment: Except family and brand names are not strictly borrowings, are they?

Comment: @Lambie: Proper names have their own Hobson-Jobson problems. It was imperative that Vicks Vaporub change its name to market to German-speaking countries: leave it and it's way to close to the German cognate to the English f-word. Change the V to a W to preserve the voiced consonant (Wicks) and it sounds like the second person informal imperative of 'masturbate.' The product is thus called "Wick," like Vic.

Comment: None of this concerns the question, which was about the OP confusing two things: One is a person's last name and the other is a foreign-sounding brand name, which is perfectly readable in English. Many times, last names are not changed. Brand names are another story. And your comment fits with your analysis. Believe me, I know all about this...

Comment: @Lambie: Except that _Castle Wolfenstein_ is a place name, albeit fictional, and not likely to be in, say, Cornwall or Sussex. Surnames also can be anglicized: _Goldwasser  >  Goldwater, Eisenhauer > Eisenhower_.

Comment: Wolfenstein does not require any changes to be read  in English.  It stays as is. You are not willing to understand what I said. So be it.

Comment: @Lambie: and what you apparently fail to understand is the prestige element in getting the pronunciation "right," which was the motivation for the question. Whatever "perfectly readable in English" means to you, it may be utterly irrelevant to a community of speakers, as is your distinction between a brand name, actually a game title and fictional place, and a surname.